# Phenotype-to-genotype mapping

Tags: statistics, biostatistics, gwas

My understanding is that GWAS or QTL attemp to extract potential SNP candidates responsible of a particular trait.

However, is there any framework that attempts to do the opposite? This is, link the phenotypic value of traits to the distribution of allelic frequencies.

For example, given a set of traits construct a classifier (i.e. SVM) for a given SNP and try to predict its allele.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenome-wide_association_study

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.